# Delete row from DataGridView data source error

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I wrote these lines for my delete button. No errors appear for me, but the button doesn't do anything and sometimes I get this error from vb

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll "" with a selection on this line from the code "" c.patientID = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxPatientID.Text);

Any idea how I can get my delete button to work?

```cs
private void btnSupprimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get Patient ID from app
    c.patientID = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxPatientID.Text);
    bool success = c.Delete(c);

    if (success == true)
    {
        // Successfully Deleted
        MessageBox.Show(" Operation reussite");
        // refresh data grid
        // Load data into DataGridView
        DataTable dt = c.Select();
        dgvContactList.DataSource = dt;
        // Call the clear method
        Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        // failed to delete
        MessageBox.Show(" Operation echouée");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that you are trying to convert non numeric or null string to Int32. I believe the problem is here:

```
c.patientID = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxPatientID.Text);
```

On other words, when you click that button and the txtBoxPatientID contains nothing or any character with or without numbers, then you will get the mentioned exception.

It's good idea to try parse the content of the text box to check whether the input is in the right format. If so, proceed otherwise, for example show a validation message.

Try:

```
int i;

if(!int.TryParse(txtBoxPatientID.Text, out i))
{
    return; //or message the user to enter a valid input.
}
// Get Patient ID from app
c.patientID = i;
bool success = c.Delete(c);
if (success == true)
{
    // Successfully Deleted
    MessageBox.Show(" Operation reussite");
    // refresh data grid
    //Load Data on Data GridView
    DataTable dt = c.Select();
    dgvContactList.DataSource = dt;
    // Call the clear method
    Clear();
}
else
{
    // failed to deleted
    MessageBox.Show(" Operation echouée");
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. with your help error is gone but the button still don't do anything i don't know why

Comment: Glad to help you. However, you need to post more details to help us understand your logic and so we can help. For example; What is the **c** object? What do the **c.Delete(c)** and **c.Select** exactly do? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you sir so much problem resolved. it's my false instead of writing delete i wrote dalete.  Stupid false